# Calculating amperage

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

So this question might be OT, if it is please re-direct me to a better forum.

I am currently interested in calculating the amperage used by an Android phone. As this is not currently supported on most devices, I tried a sort of mathematical approach. My gut tells me that it my method is wrong, but I cannot find any mathematical proof that I am way off.

So, my thought was:

1. Find the maximum mAh for the battery (can be done by either reading on battery pack or through code)
2. Listen for battery changes, for instance 90% drops to 89%.
3. Monitor the time from 90% to 89%

When I have gathered the data, I figured that average milliampere used during this time must be `max mAh` * `percentage change` (i.e. 1% == 0.01) / `delta time in hours`. If assuming that dropping from x % to y% means losing the same amount of ampere, the time should be the decisive factor. Is this correct mathematical thinking? Or where in my reasoning am I wrong?

Comment: What you are not considering is other factors that influence amperage. Eg. Taking you phone to a low network zone, or using 3G/4G service etc. Technically, you want to calculate standby time for the phone, which is not a simple multiplication.

Comment: If I can capture the exact moment when the percentage drops, shouldn't that at least be able to give an average over the last 1%?

Comment: This belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that the percent full readout is in charge (mA-hr), not in energy (which has an extra factor of the battery voltage.)  They are not equivalent as the voltage changes with state of charge. [This figure](https://www.google.com/search?q=lithium%20ion%20battery%20voltage%20vs%20charge&rlz=1C1GGGE___US546US548&espv=2&biw=1402&bih=720&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=kn70VMnLAYKXoQSYsoCwCg&ved=0CDAQsAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=abuh2y7_2BM_jM%253A%3BJidUBB-pv3nT8M%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.powerstream.com%252Fz%252Fli-charge-voltage.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.powerstream.com%252Flithuim-ion-charge-voltage.htm%3B616%3B737) shows the voltage dropping from around 4V at end of charge to 3.5V before the voltage falls off a cliff.  You are also assuming that the percent full readout is accurate, which may or may not be true.  Otherwise your approach is fine.  You might want to go over a larger range of percent full to smooth out the noise more, say from 90% to 80%.

Comment: I never thought of the voltage, that was the missing piece!

Comment: I don't know whether the percent full includes a factor of voltage or not.  I also don't know how the phone power consumption (in any particular usage mode) varies with battery voltage.  Most of it is probably constant power, but there could be some constant current load as well.  Probably you would like the percent full to be in energy, not charge, to be closer to representing the amount of time you can use the phone before the battery dies.